# Delayed display of MC in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I came across this previous thread ([Delay Display of Text in Qualtrics using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001819/delay-display-of-text-in-qualtrics-using-javascript)) when searching for how to do a delayed display of a MC question in Qualtrics.

The thread was from about a year ago- wondering if Qualtrics has any built in ways to do delayed display? Are the solutions provided in the thread the way to go?

Basically, I liked to display text first, and after a few seconds, have a multiple choice question display under the text. I would still like the original text to be visible to the user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built in way. Yes, the answers from the previous question still apply. However, if you want to hide an entire question the code would be a little different. Add this js to the question(s) you want to temporarily hide:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).hide();
});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    var q = $(this.questionId);
    (function () {q.show();}).delay(5);
});
```

This doesn't do anything with the question separators. You'd have to add a couple lines code if you want to hide and show those too.

Comment: okay great- I think i'd add something like   $(this.question._$separator).hide() if i wanted to hide the separator

Comment: No, it would be $(this.questionId).previous('.Separator').hide();